# Differing length of matplotlib.pyplot.pcolorfast edges on symlog scale

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently trying to create a coloured grid plot on a logarithmic scale using . As I want to include the area from 0 to 1, I'm using "symlog" as a scale instead of "log".

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
Z = np.random.random(size=(RATE_EXPONENT + 1,  BLOCK_EXPONENT + 1))
x_edges = [0] + [AXIS_BASE ** i for i in range(RATE_EXPONENT + 1)]
y_edges = [0] + [AXIS_BASE ** i for i in range(BLOCK_EXPONENT + 1)]
ax.set_xbound(0.0, MAX_FEE_RATE)
ax.set_ybound(0.0, MAX_CONFIRMATION_BLOCKS)
ax.set_xlabel('Fee rate in satoshis / byte')
ax.set_ylabel('Confirmation time in blocks')
ax.set_xscale('symlog')
ax.set_yscale('symlog')
ax.set_xticks(x_edges)
ax.set_yticks(y_edges)
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())

colour_map = colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('GreenRed', ['red', 'green'], N=256)
ax.pcolorfast(x_edges, y_edges, Z, cmap=colour_map)
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, the edges aren't quite predictably spaced to the point where I'd know how to input my data and in fact, the edges are moved depending on the zoom factor.

For reference, this is what it looks like all zoomed out
[image: For reference, this is what it looks like all zoomed out]

and this is what it looks like when you zoom into the interval from 2 to 4
[image: and this is what it looks like when you zoom into the interval from 2 to 4]

As you can see, the grid edges move as I zoom in. I'd also like for the edges to be placed at the same intervals as the axis ticks, however I've not found anything useful in the pyplot docs.

Any help would be much appreciated!

PS: Using a linear instead of a symlog scale works. Same thing when using xlim / ylim.

[image: For reference, here's an image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh` instead of `matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolorfast`. The docstring of `pcolorfast` says that it is experimental and

> "...it lacks support for log scaling of the axes...",

as of the current version 2.0.0.

Comment: Such a simple solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: not only for log scales, controlling the axis in `matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolorfast` is very hard, if possible.